# Fluorescent bulbs won’t stay on. They come back on when I turn them, but then go off again the next day

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

When I come in the morning, the bulbs are off. When i twist one bulb, all of the bulbs come back on, only to shut off again the next day.

Comment: Are these the tube style florescents or the A type bulb that screws into a socket (a "standard" or "normal" light socket)

Comment: We're going to need a lot more information to help you. Pics of the light fixtures would help, too.

Comment: I will take a SWAG and assume they are bi-pin lamps maybe on the order of F40CW or similar. Test them in another fixture if you can. If the tubes are a year or more older best to replace them. If they are new be sure the number matches the older one. I have seen where the older tubes are placed in a new energy efficient and they will not light. If that does not solve it then it is probably the ballast (can be electronic). The electronic ones do not last light the old magnetic ones did. You may be able to replace it, check at your local big box store no guarantee they have one for you.

Comment: When you say "when I come in the morning", that sounds like an office / commercial space.  Yes???  While we need more info on the exact model of fixture and bulbs (pics help), commercial spaces can be wired quite differently than residential, like some lighting can be in series.  Sounds like you have a loose connection. Does it matter which bulb you screw in to get the lights to come on?   If commercial, there may also be some lighting control systems.  Does the switch not turn on the bulbs?  Is there a switch?